# ERR unknown command `publish` Miniredis Golang

Tags: go, redis

I'm testing this small code fragment using [miniredis](https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis) mock for Redis. `repository.client` is a functioning mock (used for other tests) that returns a Redis client.

```
    err := repository.client.Publish(ctx, "UPDATE", "MESSAGE").Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.fatal(err.Error())
    }
```

When I run the test it logs me the following error:

```
ERR unknown command `publish`, with args beginning with: `UPDATES`, `MESSAGE`,
```

I'm confused by the fact that miniredis should implement pub-sub functionalities. Any clue of what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching on owner's repository I found out that the issue was related to the imported version. In online articles, it is normally cited the import `github.com/alicebob/miniredis`, but it doesn't have implemented pub/sub functionalities. To make them work it is important to import **V2**:

```
github.com/alicebob/miniredis/v2
```

Source: https://github.com/alicebob/miniredis/issues/157